# Panasonic TSP crash

Tags: c++, tapi

I have a program that use panasonic TSP to receive events from panasonic PBX and then do certain actions on received events.
I never call any function that create an state change in PBX and only interested on events, so I only use `lineGetCallInfo` and `lineGetCallStatus`.
Now I have a problem:
 Panasonic TSP create an access violation in `svchost.exe`(windows telephony service) and thus I can't get events from TAPI.

My boss resist that it is some problem in my use of TAPI, but I only use few functions, does any one has same problem or know where should I find more information? or even how should I debug this error?

I'm programming with C++
TAPI 2 interface with IOCP
and my program is running on Windows Server 2003
My PBX is TDA600 with really high load

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify when or how often the TSP crashes?

One possible explanation could be that even if you use few functions the TSP may expect you to call 'lineDeallocateCall' on a callstate 'idle' event so the TSP knows it can clear the memory. Neglecting to do so may lead to overflow of buffers and access violations. Of course, that would require some sloppy programming on Panasonic's part, but it's a theory.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I have a class for call object that automatically call `lineDeallocateCall` on its destructor. So it can't be the problem, because my program does not have a memory leak so I assume all call objects will be closed as expected

Comment: Ok, so that is probably not it. Could you possibly add your code for the function calls to the question? And does the access violation occur consistently? If so, sharing that info would really help. Maybe there is a problem in the way you allocate/specify the buffer passed with LineGetCallInfo.